# How do I reference the default `this` reference in Actionscript3 from an external package?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4

My code is an external `.as` file. Google provides this code on their [demo](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/flashTrackingSetupFlash.html#useAnalyticsLibrary), which contains the `this` keyword:

```
import com.google.analytics.AnalyticsTracker; 
import com.google.analytics.GATracker; 
var tracker:AnalyticsTracker = new GATracker( this, "UA-111-222", "AS3", true ); 
playGame.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, onButtonClick ); 
function onButtonClick ( event:Event ):void 
{
   tracker.trackPageview("/myGame1"); 
}
```

This code probably works fine in the default context, but since I am embedding this code in an external `.as` file where I define a package, obviously the `this` reference differs since the execution context is different.

Currently, this is how I have it:

```
package {
        import flash.display.MovieClip;
        import flash.display.Sprite;
        import flash.events.Event;
        import flash.events.MouseEvent;
        import flash.net.URLRequest;
        import flash.net.navigateToURL;
        import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
        import flash.text.TextFormat;
        import flash.external.ExternalInterface;    

        import com.google.analytics.AnalyticsTracker; 
        import com.google.analytics.GATracker; 

        public class DetailView extends MovieClip {

                //private var tracker:GATracker;
                private var tracker:AnalyticsTracker;

                function slugify(text) {
                        text = text.replace(/[^-a-zA-Z0-9,&\s]+/ig, '');
                        text = text.replace(/-/gi, "_");
                        text = text.replace(/\s/gi, "-");
                        return text.toLowerCase();
                }   

                public static var NEXTOFFER:String = "DETAIL_NEXTOFFER";
                public static var TERMS:String = "DETAIL_TERMS";
                private var link:String;
                private var fbshare:String;
                private var twshare:String;
                private var offerID:Number;
                private var details:Sprite;
                private var terms:Sprite;

                public function DetailView() {
                        ExternalInterface.call( "console.log", 'before');
                        ExternalInterface.call( "console.log", typeof GATracker );
                        ExternalInterface.call( "console.log", typeof this );
                        tracker = new GATracker( this, "UA-WATEVER", "AS3", true );  
                        ExternalInterface.call( "console.log", 'after');
```

Notice that I have 4 calls to `console.log`. The first 3 fire, but after the `new GATracker` statement, the 4th does not fire.

I have a feeling that I'm overriding the entire package with the object created from `new GATracker` when I should be passing a different context.

I believe the correct context I should pass is whatever `this` defaults to when not inside of a package/external file, I assume it references the main stage object.

If my assumption is right, how would I reference the main stage object from inside of the constructor?

Comment: Are you getting any runtime errors?

Comment: I do not get any Compiler Errors, the swf saves out fine.

Comment: Just a suggestion, with a rep of 42.1k, you seem to be a knowledgable coder. I'd recommend not using the Flash IDE and getting comfortable with an editor like FlashDevelop ( open source but windows only ), FlashBuilder or similar. The IDE is no good for writing and debugging code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reference the main stage, you need to wait until your object is added to the stage before you can reference it.

It might look something like this:

```
public function DetailView()
{
     addEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage );
}

protected function onAddedToStage( event:Event ):void 
{
     tracker = new GATracker( this, "UA-WATEVER", "AS3", true );  
     removeEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage );
}
```

Another approach to this is listening to the ENTER_FRAME event and in the handler checking for a non-null value for the stage, then removing the handler and initializing your vars.

Comment: Hm, so `stage` will be defined when I pass it? Trying this out now.

Comment: You shouldn't pass stage through it though, you should still pass this.  Inside GATracker it will try to access the stage object of whatever you pass, so in this example it will try to access `this.stage.stage`

Comment: @shanethehat, good point, I wasn't aware of the internals of GATracker, only providing insight into when the stage object is available, i've updated the snippet

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your class object is not on the stage when you try to initialize the tracker.  Looking at the source for GATracker, the reference to `this` that you pass in is used to obtain the swf url from the stage loaderInfo object: [Line 218](http://code.google.com/p/gaforflash/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/analytics/GATracker.as).

This will fail if whatever displayObject you pass in where currently you use `this` is not on the stage:

```
//_display contains a reference to the first property from the constructor
_env.url = _display.stage.loaderInfo.url;
```

The solutions are either:

1. as jeremynealbrown suggests, to add a listener for `ADDED_TO¬STAGE` and only initiate your tracker at that point.
2. pass a reference into the class of an object that is already on the stage, and use that reference in place of `this`. The scope you pass for that first parameter is irrelevent as long as the object is on the stage.